# How to find the location of uploaded file in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, gridfs

I recently download a code. What I can't understand is how to upload and read file by using mongoDB and mongoose.

Here's the code and my understanding.

In app.js, mongoose connect to mongoDB while in myDB.js defines where the data will be stored.

app.js

```
mongoose.connect(myDB.db);
mongoose.connection.on('connected', (connection) => {   
    gfs = new GridFsStorage('/data')
    gfs.on('ready', function() {
        setupModelRoutes(mongoose.connection.db)
    })
})
```

myDB.js

```
module.exports = {
    db: process.env.MONGODB || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myData',
    gridFs: process.env.GRIDFS || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test',
};
```

I suppose I can find my uploaded file in "myData". However, there're no "myData" file in my computer. I didn't create it.

But suprisingly, the mongoDB and mongoose seems working. I can upload and read my uploaded files in the browser, but I cannot find where the files are stored.

I checked the default path of my mongoDB, which is /data/db. Seems that the data are not stored in the folder. I'm wondering where the data is actually being stored and stored in what kind of type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking a  the wrong place.

You need to query the [GridFS collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#gridfs-collections) for this.
As mentioned in the documentation:

> GridFS stores files in two collections:
>
> - chunks stores the binary chunks. For details, see [The chunks Collection.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#gridfs-chunks-collection)
> - files stores the file’s metadata. For details, see [The files Collection.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#gridfs-files-collection)